# Kafka: Java client that blocks read and doesn't poll

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I was wondering if there is a java client code that is a Kafka Consumer that enables to read data via push notification / a blocking read, instead of the current poll:

```
 final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
     new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100); //poll
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                {
                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(),
                            record.value());
                    System.out.println();
                    callback.onMessage(record.value());
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly you wish for the data to be pushed to consumer when available instead of having the consumer being responsible of  checking from new data and pulling.

On `https://kafka.apache.org/08/design.html` they discuss push vs. pull and the choice that was made in Kafka where the producer push the messages to the broker and the consumer pulls from broker. They also mention the attempts they have made to prevent the downsides of a pull-based approach. If you require a pushing pub/sub messaging system you may want to look at Scribe or Flume which is also mentioned in the link :)